Change value of a variable each time a Quick Action is executed
I recently upgraded to a MacBook Pro 2020, and I've been messing with Quick actions with Automator for the Touch Bar (which is awesome btw).
I want my Quick Action to increase a variable for each time it is run, so that I can access the amount of times I've executed the Quick Action.
Is this possible?

You could possibly use an extended attribute such as a file comment or Finder comment, although I don't know of a way to get the path of a running Quick Action workflow programmatically.
